# No entiendo, por que no me reproduce los videos automáticamente cuando los inserto en mi web, pero solo me falla en Iphone

Tags: css, html5, scss, xhtml

Este es el html,No entiendo muy bien que tendría que hacer

```
<div>
     <video src="imagenes/pop3.mp4" autoplay loop muted 
     class="video-clase"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡No podemos adivinar! Sin un [repro] es difícil ayudar. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

El `autoplay` para los videos ha sido todo un tema, porque es algo invasivo. Hace unos años comenzó una moda de poner videos en loop como elementos de diseño en la Web, por lo que se acordó permitir la reproducción automatica siempre y cuando tuviera tambien el atributo `muted`. Safari para iPhone fue el último en implementar esto (al parecer nunca le gusto mucho la idea), por lo que si tienes un dispositivo viejo (me parece que inferior iOS 10) no hay solución

En safari necesitas agregar el atributo [playsinline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#playsinline) tal como indica la [documentación de mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#handling_autoplay_failure_with_media_controls)

```
<div>
     <video src="imagenes/pop3.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline
     class="video-clase"></video>
</div>
```

Además en iPhone existe el "Modo de bajo consumo" o "ahorro de batería" esto también puede provocar que el dispositivo bloquee la reproducción automática. En este caso no existe manera por parte del desarrollador de saltar el bloqueo

Por ultimo, tambien puede existir el caso que tu video tenga un codec no compatible con safari